# equivalent of c++ freopen in c, as safe as possible

Tags: c++, c

I am used to C++ in competitive programming. Below is my C++ temaplate:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a * 4 << " " << a * a;
}
```

I want a safe equivalent in C, I tried to find it on my own, but found many versions.

I have found the following equivalent, is that the one you'd recommend?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   FILE* inp = freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
   FILE* out = freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
   int a;
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("%d %d", a*4, a*a);
   fclose(stdout);
}
```

Is this safe and optimal?

Comment: The only difference is that you ignore the return values of `freopen` in the first, and explicitly close `stdout` in the second. Why do you think the second isn't "safe" or "optimal"?

Comment: Why would you think `freopen()` isn't safe?  If you're using Microsoft's Visual Studio, read this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt#Microsoft, then this:  https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations

Comment: what do you mean by 'in the first'?

Comment: I need to do that `FILE * inp = ...` instead of just `freopen ...` ?

Comment: You don't use `inp` and `out` anyway, so why do you save them?

Comment: should I close both `inp` and `out` ?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen *should I close both `inp` and `out`?*  No.  Those are only used as error indicators by `freopen()` - they'll be `NULL` if `freopen()` failed for some reason.  For code like this, you don't really need them.

Comment: Please specify in your question what you understand as "optimal". The question does not tell what you expect your program to do. We can only see what the code does. The code lacks error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code snippet is equivalent to the first one, except that you ignore the return value of `freopen` in the former, and save it in the later.

> If the file is successfully reopened, the function returns the pointer
> passed as parameter "stream", which can be used to identify the
> reopened stream. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned. On most
> library implementations, the errno variable is also set to a
> system-specific error code on failure.

I'd say the second one might be
more *secure*, as `freopen` returns `NULL` on failure, and `inp` and
`oup` can be used to check for an error.

> If a new filename is specified, the function first attempts to close
> any file already associated with stream (third parameter) and
> disassociates it. Then, independently of whether that stream was
> successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file specified by
> filename and associates it with the stream just as fopen would do
> using the specified mode.

*independently of whether that stream was successfuly closed or not* suggests that it could remain open, or be in some error state. But failure to close the original stream shall be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this safe and optimal?

Neither is safe as the return values of `freopen()` and `scanf()` are not checked.

Suggest add error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   FILE* inp = freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
   if (inp == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reopen stdin.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   FILE* out = freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
   if (out == NULL) {
     fclose(inp);
     fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reopen stdout.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   int a;
   if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an int.\n");
   } else {  
     printf("%d %d", a*4, a*a);
   } 
   fclose(stdin);
   fclose(stdout);
}
```

Comment: I read that 'fclose(stdout);' is not advisable

Comment: @user21078706 Does that advice apply to the case where `stdout` is re-opened?  Post a link to that advise if possible.

Comment: I just read somewhere that `fopen` is better, can you demonstrate how to check for return value when using `fopen` without `FILE * ...`?